# CK editor destroy the style of the page even in Inline mode.. how to disable?

Tags: javascript, styles, format, ckeditor, code-editor

what i think to do for my cms is this

```
<script type=javascript...... src=ckeditor.js>    
<div contentditable=true>
\all of Site code\
</div>
```

then submit it to database..

the problem is that when i do this the ckeditor disables iframes, swfs, list styles and destroy the style of the page

My goal is like:

Inline Edit with that acts like `codeditable="true"` with the toolbars of the ckeditor...

it destroys alignments especially make navbars in UL into default list style and others

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it the wrong way. CKEditor is not a website editor, therefore it cannot be used to edit entire website with full spectrum of CSS/HTML/JS used.

It should be rather understood as a "documents" editor. So it should be used to edit semantically consistent, more atomic fragments of the web page. Check the CKEditor integrations for popular CMSes like for example for [Drupal](https://drupal.org/).

Also, make sure that you know about the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Answer (score 0):

Instead on a div with contentEditable=true you should put the page that you want to edit as the content of a textarea (of course, encoding it properly) and then set CKEditor to use fullPage mode and that way you'll be able to edit a whole page.

Comment: full page mode? can i have the link of that?? i tried what u said in the text are and it disable all the css styles >.<

Comment: Here's the official sample: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-07-06-13-05/full/samples/plugins/wysiwygarea/fullpage.html. 
Remember that you must put ALL the content that you want to edit inside the textarea (after all in your description you state "all of Site code"). Our you can use the textarea in normal mode and specify the contentsCss to point to your stylesheet.